# Playing video on texture view with aspect ratio of video

Tags: android, textureview

I am playing video from my server on surface using texture view, but its stretching the video and not able maintain aspect ratio of video. But, I wish to maintain aspect ratio as per the video as in vine app or instagram app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can either change the size of the View (using a custom FrameLayout), or use the TextureView matrix to change the way the texture is rendered.

Examples of both can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  The "Play video (TextureView)" activity demonstrates configuring the matrix to match the aspect ratio of a video.  See the `adjustAspectRatio()` method, the core of which is:

```
    Matrix txform = new Matrix();
    mTextureView.getTransform(txform);
    txform.setScale((float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
    txform.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);
    mTextureView.setTransform(txform);
```

Note it centers as well as scales the video.

Comment: @fadden please check this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988063/how-can-i-scale-video-in-exoplayer-v2-play-video-in-full-screen using expoplayer is it possible to ply in center

Answer (score 9):

Well I am too late to answer but as I  got from [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java) you may use this function

```
 private void adjustAspectRatio(int videoWidth, int videoHeight) {
    int viewWidth = mTextureView.getWidth();
    int viewHeight = mTextureView.getHeight();
    double aspectRatio = (double) videoHeight / videoWidth;

    int newWidth, newHeight;
    if (viewHeight > (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio)) {
        // limited by narrow width; restrict height
        newWidth = viewWidth;
        newHeight = (int) (viewWidth * aspectRatio);
    } else {
        // limited by short height; restrict width
        newWidth = (int) (viewHeight / aspectRatio);
        newHeight = viewHeight;
    }
    int xoff = (viewWidth - newWidth) / 2;
    int yoff = (viewHeight - newHeight) / 2;
    Log.v(TAG, "video=" + videoWidth + "x" + videoHeight +
            " view=" + viewWidth + "x" + viewHeight +
            " newView=" + newWidth + "x" + newHeight +
            " off=" + xoff + "," + yoff);

    Matrix txform = new Matrix();
    mTextureView.getTransform(txform);
    txform.setScale((float) newWidth / viewWidth, (float) newHeight / viewHeight);
    //txform.postRotate(10);          // just for fun
    txform.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);
    mTextureView.setTransform(txform);
}
```

Comment: is it possible use with exoplayer

Comment: @SagarHudge yeah sure you can use exolplayer to play videos, this question is for those who are not using any thirdparty library for playing videos

Comment: I want to play video in full screen vertically but it stretch vertically  on `FILL` resize ,I want to fill and center crop

Comment: ask a seperate question with the code you tried and also attach some screenshots

Comment: please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988063/exoplayer-play-video-in-full-screen thank you

Comment: @UmarAta Say, do you know perhaps how to do it for top-scale-crop, instead of center-crop? I asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54216273/878126

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer# and check the full demo. It maintains the video aspect ratio perfectly.

Comment: It can't handle animation perfectly.

Comment: it can depending of the View you use to display the video. (SurfaceView or TextureView, google the diff for more details)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on fadden's answer above:
If you want to align the video in another way other than just center it,
modify these lines in the Grafika's "adjustAspectRatio()" code:

```
int xoff = (viewWidth - newWidth) / 2;
int yoff = (viewHeight - newHeight) / 2;
```

to:

```
int xoff = 0; //align left
```

or

```
int xoff = (viewWidth - newWidth); // align right
```

or

```
int yoff = 0; // align top
```

or

```
int yoff = (viewHeight - newHeight); // align bottom
```