# How can I scale video in ExoPlayer-V2 - Play Video In Full Screen

Tags: aspect-ratio, exoplayer

I am playing video from `URL` on `Exoplayer`, it stretching the video on resizing/on using `resize_mode` as I have mentioned in layout file using this I am not able to maintain the aspect ratio of video.

I want to do scale type `CENTER_CROP` like we do in `TextureSurface` as mentioned in **image2** but I am getting output as **image1**

I have tried following example

[Exoplayer Demo Example](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer#)

My Output **(Img 1)** and Expected Output **(Img 2)**

[image]

> exoplayer layout code

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
      android:id="@+id/player_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:resize_mode="fill" />
```

With this line `app:resize_mode="fill"` it  fit the video in screen but stretch vertically,
So how can I solve this .

Comment: if want to play video in full screen then you must use the same orientation on app as of video, like landscape for landscape video, otherwise landscape video will get played in center of scrren in potrait mode

Comment: @UmarAta is it possible to it  like we do in  `TextureSurface` scale type CENTERE_CROP ?

Comment: what exactly you want

Comment: @UmarAta I have uploaded screen shot of out put please check

Comment: check this https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2016

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Following two lines helped me to play video in full-screen mode.**

Using `app:resize_mode` in layout file this somehow help but it stretches the video as mentioned in the question picture.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      app:resize_mode="...."
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Try changing `AspectRatioFrameLayout` to `FILL,FIT,ZOOM...` as per yout requirement, changing below line worked for me.

```
exoVideoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
```

Bellow line will ensure that aspect ratio is correctly maintained even for 4:3 videos.

```
exoPlayer.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
```

Also you can try changing `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING` in `exoplayer`

Comment: The line `exoVideoView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);` should be changed to `playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);`.  This will ensure that aspect ratio is correctly maintained even for 4:3 videos.

Comment: Say, do you know how to do it for top-scale-crop, instead of center-crop? I asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54216273/878126

Comment: my player view is not in center, it placed on top (height and width is match_parent), how I can make it center ()? Note - giving top margin to playerview won't work (if I do so player view become smaller).

Comment: @BajrangHudda try giving padding

Comment: I was getting problems with layout_width MATCH_CONSTRAINT & layout_height WRAP_CONTENT when used with resizeMode ``fit``, the video was getting stretched vertically. But using ``setResizeMode(...fixed_width)`` programmatically fixed this...

Answer (score 23):

To maintain center crop in exo player below code worked for me:

Java code:

```
playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
```

or you can use from xml:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="zoom"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: After setting to zoom video does not play only image display.

Answer (score 9):

Following are the Resize Mode options to play around with

```
app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
app:resize_mode="fixed_height"
app:resize_mode="fill"
app:resize_mode="fit"
app:resize_mode="zoom"
```

You can try each one to see its affect on your container.

Comment: I notice that `fit` is default, but what's the difference between `fill` and `zoom`?

Comment: @SamChen, `fill` will stretch the video destroying the ratio of the video. But, `zoom` will crop the video to fit to the screen maintaining the ratio. And thanks @DragonFire. It helped. Upvoted

Answer (score 6):

My issue was solved using below lines:

```
playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
exoPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

Comment: In version 2.12.1. It will be this: 
playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);        simpleExoPlayer?.setVideoScalingMode(Renderer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT)

Comment: dont forget to add  `app:surface_type="texture_view"` in PlayerView

Comment: @iamkdblue what is the use of app:surface_type="texture_view" ?

Comment: Is there any alternative of setVideoScalingMode as this is not present in exoplayer library i.e 2.16

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy

The app:surface_type attribute in the StyledPlayerView determines the type of surface used for video rendering. There are two main options: surface_view and texture_view.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy
surface_view (default): This option uses a dedicated SurfaceView for video rendering. SurfaceView is more efficient for video playback as it renders directly to a separate surface layer without going through the view hierarchy. It allows for better performance, particularly for high-resolution videos, and provides better hardware-accelerated scaling and rendering. However, SurfaceView has some limitations when it comes to handling view transformations, such as rotations, translations, or animations, as it's not part of the standard view hierarchy.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy
texture_view: This option uses a TextureView for video rendering. TextureView is part of the standard view hierarchy and supports view transformations, such as rotations, translations, or animations, which makes it more suitable for certain use cases where these transformations are needed. However, TextureView can be less efficient compared to SurfaceView for video playback, particularly for high-resolution videos, as it involves an extra step of rendering to a texture before being displayed on the screen.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy
By setting app:surface_type="texture_view" in your StyledPlayerView, you are choosing to use a TextureView for video rendering instead of the default SurfaceView. This is useful if you need more flexibility in handling view transformations or animations, but it may come at the cost of slightly lower performance, especially for high-resolution videos.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin :

```
    AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().fillMaxHeight().fillMaxWidth(),
    factory = {
        StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
            this.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
        }
    })
```