ExoPlayer video has stretched width
I am developing an Android application where I need to display video. When the app launches and plays a video using AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM, the video is expected to fill the screen.
However, the video's width appears stretched on my Pixel 7a (Android 14) and the Android Studio's emulator Pixel 7a (Android 14). When I tried RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT - the problem persisted.
After the app goes to the background and then opens from the recent apps, the video looks like it should from the start.
This bug doesn't appear if I use the Android View system instead of Kotlin Compose.
ExoplayerscalingproblemTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    AndroidView(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        factory = {
                            PlayerView(it).apply {
                                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                )
                                this.useController = false
                                setKeepContentOnPlayerReset(true)
                                this.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                            }
                        },
                        update = {
                            it.player = exoPlayer
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've created repository with code reproducing this issue; there is also a branch with Android Views instead of compose.
I'd appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!
Edit: adding photos here
Here is what I have:

Here is what I want:


resize_mode - Controls how video and album art is resized within the view. Valid values are fit, fixed_width, fixed_height, fill and zoom.

try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988063/how-can-i-scale-video-in-exoplayer-v2-play-video-in-full-screen

@Maveňツ Hi. Thanks for your response! I am using valid values for resize mode. It is not a problem. On other devices(for example, the OnePlus 8 Pro), I have the expected behavior. The solution you've shared doesn't help me either: RESIZE_MODE_FILL isn't the desired behavior for me, as it ignores the video's aspect ratio.

Did you find any solution to this?

to be honest I do not remember, sorry @OverMind
